# CSS hide div on mouse hover but it is blinking

Tags: html, css, hover

I just make up this sample html and css to hide a div on mouse hover. However, When I mouse over it, the div is blinking. Please anyone tell me what is going on here and how can i fix it with just css (no java please). Here is a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh24urbm) of what I have.

### Code Snippet:

```css
        .container{
        border:1px solid gray;
        height:150px;
        width:200px;
        background-image:     url("http://i934.photobucket.com/albums/ad184/giangvy1011/trade_zps7af1d79c.png");
        background-size:100% 100%;
    }

    .description{
        position:relative;
        top:100px;
        height:50px;
        width:200px;
        background:rgba(215,40,40,0.9); 
        color:white
    }
    .description:hover{
        display:none;
    }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
        <div class='description'>
            This is description
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
.description:hover{
    display:none;
}
```

To this:

```
.container:hover .description{
    display:none;
}
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/dh24urbm/2/

Answer (score 1):

When you hover on `.description` it was hide, In that condition you were not hovered on `.description` because it was hidden already.
Then there was no `.description` and no mouse hover on that and it was show again, after showing `.description` once again mouse hover work on it and it happen again and again, and it looks like blinking.

Conclusion is:

you should hover on parent div:

```
.container:hover .description{
   display:none;
}
```

One more solution I have found:

```css
.container {
    border:1px solid gray;
    height:150px;
    width:200px;
    background-image: url("http://i934.photobucket.com/albums/ad184/giangvy1011/trade_zps7af1d79c.png");
    background-size:100% 100%;
display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    
}

.description {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background:rgba(215,40,40,0.9); 
    color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:1;
}
.description-hover {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    background:none; 
    display:inline-block;
    z-index:2;
}
.description-hover:hover + div {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <div class='description-hover'></div>
    <div class='description'>
        This is description
    </div>
</div>
```